# What permission is needed to call System.setPassword

Tags: apex, system-permissions

I am really stuck trying to find this anywhere in the documentation.

What permission is needed to be able to invoke `System.setPassword()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's System Permissions > Users > Reset User Passwords and Unlock Users.

I tested this by running anon apex with a Standard User with and without the above permission.  It threw an exception without that perm and went through ok after I added it.

The user had to have View All Data and Author Apex in order to run this in the Developer Console.